# ElasticSearch: more_like_this query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, similarity, morelikethis

I have an index = "es_demo" , where I need to find similar documents to given  "_id",
I don't think it is working as the returned results have same "_id" as mentioned in the query .
And as written in the [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) having "include" parameter as "false" will not be returning the "ids" mentioned in the query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": "_doc",
      "like": {
        "docs": [
          {
            "_id": "5fac83afdce931230ef44c0a"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5f80096adce931230e8bdb2d"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "include": "false"
}
```

Can someone please help me out here I think the query I wrote is wrong.

I also tried these queries :

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": "_doc",
      "like": [
        {
          "_id": "5fac83afdce931230ef44c0a"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f80096adce931230e8bdb2d"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": "_doc",
      "like": [
        {
          "_id": "5fac83afdce931230ef44c0a"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f80096adce931230e8bdb2d"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": "False"
}
```

The first result I got was the same document with **"_id": "5fac83afdce931230ef44c0a"** for every query

Comment: what is the "_doc"?

Comment: its the "_doc" type I thought it was necessary  for the query

Answer (score 0):

The query below works for my index movies.

Remember about parameter fields:

> A list of fields to fetch and analyze the text from. Defaults to the
> index.query.default_field index setting, which has a default value of
> *. The * value matches all fields eligible for term-level queries, excluding metadata fields.

Query (edit for you case)

```
GET idx_movies/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "title"
  ],
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [
        "title", "description"
      ],
      "like": [
        {
          "_id": "GjP1WYUBQB-6H-4Z96IG"
        }
      ],
      "min_term_freq":1
    }
  }
}
```